# Update each row value until it goes 0

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm an creating an inventory program for a company .I have a table with data on SQL Server

```
 |product|stock |
 |A      |15    |
 |B      |26    |
 |C      |27    |
 |D      |18    |
```

I want to subtract a quantity *x=70* on each product on the table until the product goes *0*. For example: subtract *x* on the product *A* until it goes *0* *(70-15=55)*. Then this difference subtracts the Product B until it goes 0 *(55-26=29)*. And so on the Product C (29-27=2). Then on Product D (18-2=16).
In the end the table would be:

```
 |product|stock |
 |A      |0     |
 |B      |0     |
 |C      |0     |
 |D      |16    |
```

I need a way to do this is SQL database.Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what does tag `c#`, `mysql` and `winforms` has to do with this ?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: so far nothing. im stack in this point on building the code for this logic. @SatishGarg

Comment: sql-server @TriV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SUM()...OVER()`

```
DECLARE @SampleTable AS TABLE
(
   Product varchar(10),
   Stock int
)
INSERT INTO @SampleTable
VALUES ('A', 15),('B', 26),('C', 27),('D', 18), ('E', 20)

DECLARE @TotalStock int = 70

SELECT st.Product , 
      CASE  
         WHEN sum(st.Stock) OVER(ORDER BY (st.Product)) < @TotalStock THEN 0
         WHEN sum(st.Stock) OVER(ORDER BY (st.Product)) - @TotalStock < st.Stock THEN sum(st.Stock) OVER(ORDER BY (st.Product)) - @TotalStock 
         ELSE st.Stock
      END AS stock
FROM @SampleTable st
```

Another approach you could use `CROSS APPLY`

```
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT *, Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS RowIndex 
   FROM @SampleTable st
)
SELECT    st.Product, 
         CASE
            WHEN ca.realstock < 0 THEN 0
            WHEN ca.realstock < st.Stock THEN ca.realstock
            ELSE st.Stock
         END AS stock
FROM temp st
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT isnull(sum(st2.Stock),0) - @TotalStock   AS realstock 
   FROM temp st2
   WHERE st2.RowIndex <= st.RowIndex
) ca
```

See demo for 2 approaches: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/CYYK5846)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `sum` to find cumulative sum of stock in the order of product (check if you need ordering on some other basis) and use that a filter rows:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(stock) over (
            order by product
            ) as cumulative_sum
    from your_table t
    ) t
where cumulative_sum - stock <= 70;
```